# Rufus crashes after deleting partitions when creating ubuntu boot disk

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, rufus

I have followed the guide from the Ubuntu website on creating a bootable USB from a Windows machine https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#5 . Whenever i click start, it will show a message in the status bar saying "deleting partitions". It lasts for about 5 seconds before the app closes without an error.

If i try to run it again, it throws an error saying the USB is in use. I cant see any instance of rufus running in task manager.

[image: Rufus config]

I found a suggestion to use https://unetbootin.github.io/ instead of rufus. This worked for me so the issue isnt the USB stick, ISO or OS. Either it's a bug with rufus or my config was wrong (which shouldnt be the case since i followed the guide).

Comment: Did you tried with another USB flash drive ? Do you have any friend that could create it from a Linux OS (quite easier...) ?

Comment: Could be a myriad of things: Do you have Controlled Folder Access enabled _(Windows Defender's ransomware protection: Settings > Update & Security > Windows Security - Open Windows Security > Virus & Threat Protection - Ransomware Protection > Manage ransomware protection)_?  If not it, try disabling Exclusive Disk Access [**ALT** + **,** (comma)], otherwise download the most recent version and/or see if the portable version works for you, as I can't replicate on the most recent portable version.

Answer (score 0):

Rufus developer here.

1. The proper place to report Rufus issues is the **[official issue tracker](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues)**. In general, if you want help with an Open Source application, you should head to the official repository for it, instead of posting the issue on external forums that may not be monitored by its developer.
2. You're the very first person I know of to report something like this, so we have to conclude that there must exist something specific in your environment that is triggering the issue, and which will be exceedingly difficult to identify unless you help. So can you please follow either one of the following steps?:

   - Rufus sends its log output to the Windows debug facility, so it may be possible to get more information about the crash from there. Can you please install and run [DebugView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) then try Rufus again and post the output you get (again, it might be more convenient to post that on the GitHub tracker than on SuperUser).
   - If at all possible (because the application is fully Open Source to ensure that users are never left stranded if they encounter a problem) the best thing you could ever do would be to install [Visual Studio 2019 community edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) then clone the [Rufus GitHub repository](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus) and debug the application in Visual Studio by opening the `.sln` file and then pressing the `Local Windows Debugger` button (after making sure you select `Debug` and `x86` for the target). Then Visual Studio should show precisely where in the code the application crashes. But of course, that requires you to be a little familiar with git and Visual Studio (and it's also a fairly large download), so I'm not sure if that's something you'd be willing to do...
   - At the very least, I would like to get the log output from when Rufus starts and before you attempt to create your drive, preferably with enumeration debug turned on, which you can do by pressing `Alt`-`.` in Rufus. Can you please post that log? Note that you can  access the log in Rufus by either pressing the log button (last small button left of the `START` button) or by pressing `Ctrl`-`L`.

Once again, because the issue seems to be specific to your environment (for the record, Rufus is downloaded about 3 million times each month, and this is one of the very few reports I've ever gotten about the application crashing, therefore this is definitely not a widespread issue that is going to be easy to replicate), it's going to be very difficult to try to address it without your involvement. So any help you can provide would be much appreciated, thanks!